# What all modules or test cases need to be tested in Regression testing?

Tags: regression-testing

Few days back I went to an interview there they asked me What all modules you will test in Regression Testing? How you find out which test cases need to be executed in Regression testing?

Answer (score 0):

Those modules that are having little or more modification in existing modules or code are required regression testing

Comment: I know that, but the question is that, if one module contains 100 test cases, then we are not going to test all 100 test cases in Regression Testing(RT). So, for RT we need only few test cases to verify whether the module has any side effects or not. So the question is how we need to decide which one or couple of test cases need to be executed from the 100 test cases in RT?

Comment: okay then refer this link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250779/are-regression-tests-the-entire-test-suite-or-a-sample-of-tests

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have some insight into which test cases cover which parts of the product.  Then when a part of the product changes, you can run just the cases that cover the change.  This isn't always easy.  In a complex piece of software, a change in one part can have an effect in a seemingly disconnected part.

The best solution I have seen to this problem is to use code coverage data.  If you know which blocks are hit by each test and you know which blocks were changed by the fix, you can know exactly which test cases to run.

If you don't have a lot of data, your best bet is to think about the change and what things it could affect and then run cases that are in those areas.